# 2D engine for both Android & iOS engine?

Tags: android, ios, html5

I want to make a simple 2d game that would run on both Android and iPhone. Since coding it separately for each platform would take some time, I thought of using an engine, that would be able to port to both platforms.

I wanted to ask, what engine would you recommend, as there are lots of them, like Corona, Marmalade, etc.

Thanks )

Comment: 'there are lots of them' : could you please quote some other framework you know of ?

Comment: We can recommend lots of them. Every framework or engine has at least a few fans :)

Comment: "which tech should I use" questions are off topic for the site.  See the [faq].

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is [Game Maker Studio](http://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker/studio), depending on your 'simple' keyword.

Answer (score 1):

http://impactjs.com/ would be a nice choice since HTML5 works for both platforms and it's pretty easy to develop there. A free option would be http://www.limejs.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-x.org) can be a good choice !

It recently add [HTML5 feature](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Download#2-Cocos2d-html5) !

It's open-source and free and have a good community and wiki and many [tutorial](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Html5) !

Check [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/news/81) for more info.